# Having property of a same class in Symfony ApiPlatform

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I have gone over the ApiPlatform SymfonyCasts and so far I love what I can do with it. However, I have hit the wall with the following scenario:

- I have a class `Contract` with property `baseContract` which points to an object on which the new object should be based upon.
- Both `denormalizationContext` and `normalizationContext` are set for all fields (for now) to `contracts:write` and `contracts:read`, respectfully.
- When I go to `/api`, both `GET` and `POST` endpoints show all properties, **but skip** the `baseContract`...

Is there some gotcha to this?

The very basic idea is that I want to be able to post something like this:

```
{
  "name": "string",
  "description": "string",
  "contractNo": "string",
  "baseContract": "/api/contacts/{some_id}
}
```

```
    /**
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ContractRepository::class)
     *
     * @ApiResource(
     *     normalizationContext={"groups": "contract:read"},
     *     denormalizationContext={"groups": "contract:write"},
     *     collectionOperations={
     *          "get",
     *          "post"
     *     },
     *     itemOperations={
     *          "get"
     *     }
     * )
     */
    class Contract
    {
......
        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Contract::class)
         * @ORM\JoinColumn()
         *
         * @Groups({"contract:read", "contract:write"})
         */
        private ?Contract $baseContract;
```

Comment: I haven't tried php7.4 new syntax for now, could you try to add one **@var null|Contract** annotation on your property ?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately, that did not do the trick :-/ Thanks!

Comment: Strange, if I omit all the configuration in `@ApiResource` and leave it at its defaults, it does show everything, including `baseContract` :-|

Comment: and with **denormalizationContext = { "groups" = {"contract:write"}}** (i mean, replace your colon by an equal and add curly braces) ?

Comment: Still the same. I have strange feeling that Serializer is hitting maxDepth and refusing to go beneath the first level in order to prevent recursion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have finally checked on my projet. As you said in the comments, it's indeed because of the recursion.

With this serialization groups configuration, you're [embedding](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization/#embedding-relations) your baseContract property.

Add an annotation **@ApiProperty(readableLink=false, writableLink=false)** to the $baseContract. It prevents the embedding behaviour and the swagger should display your field.

Comment: My bad, i was focused on the swagger view.

Comment: What puzzles me, that I haven't stumbled upon those properties in any of the docs. Subsequent search showed only the `identifier` property. Maybe I went through the docs a bit too fast... :)

Comment: It is an [issue on github](https://github.com/api-platform/core/issues/1001#issuecomment-394162998) i'v found some month ago